# Error XML en proyecto java

Tags: java, xml, scala

Tengo varios xml generados en un proyecto java, y hay uno solo que me da errores al intentar mostrar los datos en pantalla.

Este es el código del archivo:

```
@(list:List[Recipe])
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<recipes>
    @for(recipe <- list){
        @_recipe(recipe)
    }
</recipes>
```

Este es el error que me muestra:

Error de lectura XML: declaración de texto o XML en un lugar distinto del principio de la entidad

Ubicación: http://localhost:9000/recipes

Número de línea 4, columna 9:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
--------^
```

He buscado escpacios o caracteres ocultos y no hay manera. Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Recuerda marcar como aceptada tu respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Localicé el fallo. En el bucle for estoy invocando otra vista de scala que muestra una receta. Ese archivo también empezaba con

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

y ahí estaba el fallo.